# Ignore the first occurence of a character if it exists later

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to understand how to implement "if then" with Regex in C#

Background: I am parsing a string that contains a token inside it, currently in order for token to be found user has to provide it with the curly brackets format e.g.

```
Some text {someToken} other text
```

With the following Regular Expression:

```
     [{](?<token>[^}]+)[}]"
```

I am able to get the token `someToken`. Now the new requirement that I got is that user should be allowed to input curly brackets as the token value, e.g.

```
Some text {{someToken}} other text
```

and the value that I will get is `{someToken}`. Is there such a thing in C# Regex as "If I have closing curly bracket, and there is another one after it, ignore the first one."?

Comment: You want to capture `{someToken}` from 2nd string right?

Comment: yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use this greedy regex:

```
{(?<token>{?[^}]+}?)}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU7rE0/3)

Comment: awesome, thanks! that worked! Would you explain how that works please?

Comment: Yes sure. As I wrote that this regex is **greedy** due to use of `.+` which will match up to the last `}` matching everything in between.

Comment: But note that this does the wrong thing when there's more than one field in a string, e.g.: `"Some text {{someToken}} other text {tokenTwo} more {tokenThree} text {lastToken}"`

Comment: Yes but not sure if multiple user submitted values are possible in same sentence.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't cover cases like {tokenTwo}_{tokenThree} or {tokenOne}{tokenTwo} :(

Comment: great!! really appreciate this! unfortunately can't give you more thumb ups!